# Drupal/MySQL Database error: data inserted greater than 10% of redo log size

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I'm working on a Drupal site (migrating it to a new host), and I've come across the following error that did not happen on the original host:

> Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size

Unfortunately, for reasons outside my control, I don't have the ability to tinker with the MySQL system parameters.

I have done a web search to see if I could find a programming work-around, but everything seems to point back to changing the parameters on the database. Is there a Drupal/PHP way around this? (Its in a part of the code which is non-critical, so even if it reduces fault tolerances it would be fine.)

Drupal version: 7
PHP version: 5.6

Comment: You have to change in my.cnf file. There is no other way to change mysql conf via php. And remember to restart the mysql service after you change.

Comment: Contact customer support of your host company. It's their job to tune MySQL settings, since you don't have access to do that.